# Django runserver error

Tags: django

When using the development server, I get this error:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3 beta 1, using settings 'book_scouts.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 283
, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 323
, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 402
, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 467
, in send_headers
    self._write(str(self.headers))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 318, in write
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 2426)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 283, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 309, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 322, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 569
, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 618, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\SocketServer.py", line 661, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 297, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer(data, write_offset, buffer_size))
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
```

I can't pin it down to any single source. It seems to happen randomly, afaik. It causes the page I'm testing to load up really long, and the page just loads fine.

Using **Django 1.3 Beta 1**

**UPDATE**: I'm using Opera/Firefox for testing now, and the problem hasn't come up since. I'm afraid to try again in Chrome.

Comment: What request triggers that? You don't press Escape in your browser before the request is complete, do you? Because that's what it looks like when you do that - the browser closes the connection and you get `connection was aborted`.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? I get that error quite a bit. When in Chrome it seems that almost half the time I refresh a page to see my changes, it does this and I have to refresh twice. Doesn't seem to happen in FF. I'm thinking it's some bug in Chrome's aggressive caching handling.

Comment: @AndiDog nope not pressing anything @Dan yes. using Chrome. Just tried on Opera, the problem hasn't come up yet. I'll keep an eye out. Thanks!

Comment: It seemed to be working fine in Opera, but when I try it again in Chrome, Opera gets affected as well. I'll keep on testing.

Comment: It's possible that Chrome does something that hangs the devserver and so if your next request is on another browser you'll get the exception there also. I'm clueless...

Comment: These are related:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912672/django-broken-pipe-in-debug-mode

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250183/python-urlopen-connection-aborted-urlopen-error-errno-10053

Comment: Run chrome with `--disable-extensions` and see if you can still duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing and asked on django-users google group. Nobody had any idea what's wrong.
It seems only I get this when I refresh the page from browser and not when I click on links inside the page.

Also just as a heads up: I tried on Python 2.6 and 2.7 both stock version (form python.org website) and ActiveState one. Same thing happens randomly.

LE: I'm getting this on the stable version of Django.

Comment: Yes, but i tested, and i also get it on Firefox and IE. I've tried debugging with pdb, line by line and nothing unusual popped out. At least if i'm not the only one with this issue then it seems that there might really be a problem somewhere. One thing that i think it should be tested is if this also happens on linux. I should setup a VM with debian on in and try.