# SocketServer causing error 10053

Tags: python, windows

Code in question https://github.com/truevision/socketbroker/blob/master/socketbroker/broker.py

Works flawlessly in Linux, on Windows I get

```
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: sounds like a firewall issue, try turning it off for a second.

Comment: firewall is disabled and I only get this error sometimes

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a host based IDS and not a firewall. I've ran into the same issue before. [Here's how I fixed it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250183/python-urlopen-connection-aborted-urlopen-error-errno-10053).