# Django in pycharm debugger (pydev) spits Broken pipe errors

Tags: python, django, pydev, pycharm

When I run django in pycharm debugger, it gets very slow and after a while it spits Broken pipe errors. any ideas how to fix this? Below you can see the outpu from the console:

```
[27/Feb/2012 15:44:24] "GET /media/tools/flexigrid/acme/images/load.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1737
[27/Feb/2012 15:44:24] "GET /contextual-help/page-help/?url=%2Fmanage%2Fblacklist%2F HTTP/1.1" 200 35
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56649)
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/.virtualenvs/acme/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/home/greg/.virtualenvs/acme/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/home/greg/.virtualenvs/acme/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/home/greg/.virtualenvs/acme/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/home/greg/.virtualenvs/acme/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/greg/.virtualenvs/acme/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 570, in __init__
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[27/Feb/2012 15:44:49] "GET /media/tools/flexigrid/acme/images/pager-first.png HTTP/1.1" 200 321
```

Comment: Do you have enough RAM? I love PyCharm, but this java beast is very memory hungry.

Comment: In my Mac (snow leopard) with 3GB, PyCharm is somewhat sluggish - my Wndows 7 PC with 4GB runs a lot more smoother.

Comment: Please verify does it help enabling 'No reload' checkbox if it's not enabled yet.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate for [Django Broken pipe in Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912672/django-broken-pipe-in-debug-mode)

It's not an issue with your code. It's the way django dev server works