# Python Paste using Bottle framework Broken Pipe Error

Tags: python, paste

I am using Bottle framework implementing the WSGI Request and response and because of the single thread issue, I changed the server into PythonWSGIServer and tested with Apache bench but the result consist of error broken pipe which is similar with this question [How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe).
I have tried the answer but to no avail.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paste/httpserver.py", line 1068, in process_request_in_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

The server code is shown below, and I have no idea how to improve the connection, using thread pool?

```
from paste import httpserver

    @route('/')
    def index():
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient(connectionString)
        db = connection.test
        collection = db.test
        return str(collection.find_one())

    application = default_app()
    httpserver.serve(application, host='127.0.0.1', port=8082)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to WSGIServer is a synchronous server, and it is not applicable for high concurrent users sending requests at the same time. In order to bypass these fallbacks, there are a lot of third-party frameworks can be used. Popular among them are Gevent greenlet libraries, Tornado, and CherryPy. All of them are based on Event-driven and asynchronous methodologies, enabling them to handle multiple concurrent users.