# Pymysql broken pipe error in CherryPy

Tags: mysql, cherrypy, pymysql

I'm trying a SELECT using pymysql and I keep getting `error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`. What am I missing? Everything works fine on my local machine, taking it to production breaks. I'm running an EC2 Micro instance.

```
    `import pymysql
    def connection():
      db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='**', 
          passwd='**',db='blog',charset='utf8')
      cur = db.cursor()

      cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
      cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
      cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
      return (cur,db) #Returns both curson and connection`
```

Code to grab data

```
       `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM nse WHERE DATE(created_at) = 
       (SELECT DATE(created_at) FROM nse ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)",)
    for r in cur.fetchall():
        STOCKS[r[2]] =dict(date=r[1],symbol=r[2],open=r[3],high=r[4],low=r[5],close=r[6],change=r[7],deals=r[8],units=r[9],value=r[10])
    return STOCKS`
```

What you pointed out was in `C` and doesn't quite meet my need.
Thank you.

Comment: Show your database connection statement and your Python code executing the SELECT please.

Comment: Hi Andrew, here's the connection code `import pymysql

def connection():
 db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='***', passwd='***', db='blog',charset='utf8')
 cur = db.cursor()

 cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
 cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
 cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
 return (cur,db)` and the query to retrieve data is `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM nse WHERE DATE(created_at) = (SELECT DATE(created_at) FROM nse ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)",)` note.  Thank you.

Comment: hmmm - Hard to read it that way.  Would you please edit your question and format that code in there?  Also, did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe

Comment: Thanks. Your resource did help. I had to pass everything through a try statement.