# Python Bottle framework becoming non-responsive

Tags: python, web-services, python-2.7

I am having some problem with using python's Bottle framework(http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) to host a webpage. It seems to work fine for certain period of time but now and then I get the following error and it fails to show the webpage. The script doesn't crash but the webpage becomes non responsive.

Any suggestions?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I also see the following error. But I'm guessing these occur if a request to a non-existent webpage/object is requested-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be similar to [How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11866792/1977778)

You received a `SIGPIPE` and this could be due to attempting to write to a closed socket. You could try to handle the exception with something like that:

```
    except socket.error, e:
        if isinstance(e.args, tuple):
            print "Errno: %d" % e[0]
            if e[0] == errno.EPIPE:
               # Caught a peer disconnection
               print "Remote host disconnected"
```