# Browsers close socket before the response is fully downloaded

Tags: python, google-chrome, http, firefox, http-headers

I have a simple Python server that uses [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server). The goal is not to show the video in a html page, or to download the video file, but to display the video in the browser directly. This is what I have so far:

```
import http.server

class SuperHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        path = self.path
        encodedFilePath = 'file.mp4'

        with open(encodedFilePath, 'rb') as videoFile:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'video/mp4')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(videoFile.read())
            print('File sent: ' + videoFile.name)

server_address = ('', 8000)
handler_class = SuperHandler
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, handler_class)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The problem that I have is that the response doesn't contain the full video. `file.mp4` is 50MB, but when I look in the network tab of either Chrome or Firefox, it says that the response is only 1MB. Is there a reason why the full file isn't transferred? Do I need to add some sort of HTTP header to make this work?

**EDIT:**

This is my code now:

```
server_address = ('', 8000)
handler_class = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, handler_class)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

I am now using the default SimpleHTTPRequestHandler's `do_GET`, but it's still not working (although the response is now 40MB/30MB instead of 1MB).

When I request `file.mp4` on Chrome, the socket connexion is closed after ~7 seconds (~5 seconds on Firefox), which makes the script throw a `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`, [because the server is still trying to write the rest of the video file on a closed socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe).

So my question is: how can I make the browser download the full response before it closes the socket?

**Additional info**

HTTP Response headers sent to the client:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.5.0
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 02:36:39 GMT
Content-type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 53038876
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 02:09:52 GMT
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `http.server` to serve static files? You could run: `python3 -mhttp.server` to serve files in a directory (assuming you use it as a quick-n-dirty hack).

Comment: Serving static files is just a part of what I want to do, so I need to code it myself.

Comment: If you are determined to use `http.server` here, look at at how `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` is implemented (`copyfile()` reads the file from disk and sends it to the user).

Comment: Where exactly can I find the implementation code of SimpleHTTPRequestHandler?

Comment: Found it! http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py

Comment: The official mercurial repository is at [http://hg.python.org/](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/http/server.py)

Comment: I get the same problem using just the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler. It seems like the browser closes the TCP connexion before the file has been fully downloaded. The python code triggers "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe". However, when I use only the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler (no inheritance), the browser can download about 30MB of the 50MBs, but that's still not good enough. Maybe there is something special to do when sending large files e.g. a http header I have to add.

Comment: `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` works (I've just tested it on a 1GB file using `curl url | wc -c` command). Do you need help with creating [an html page that uses the video file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#.3Cvideo.3E_element_examples)?

Comment: It woks fine when the request type is "document" - when the file is being directly downloaded on your disk by the browser. However, when the request type is "media" (e.g. "video/mp4"), which is used to display a video directly in the browser, just as you can view a pdf in a browser, the browser seems to close the connexion, thus the video file isn't completely downloaded. I am not trying to show the video file in an html file, I am trying to show the video directly in the browser, using it's built-in player.

Comment: It seems like after ~7 seconds, Chrome closes the connexion and Firefox after ~5 seconds. I tested multiple times, I'm gonna look into this...

Comment: you should change your question: "how to **stream** a video file so that it can be played using Chrome, Firefox"

Comment: But is it streaming that I am attempting to do? Am I not trying to simply serve a video file? Maybe it's the same thing.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do.  Whatever you are trying to do your code is broken for large files  (don't use `.read()` that loads the whole file into memory), use `copyfile` as I've mentioned above (to read files in chunks).

Comment: I am trying to make the browser display a video. I am not using the code above anymore, I am just using the default SimpleHTTPRequestHandler. It still causes a `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`, when accessing to a large .mp4.

Comment: Add a [Content-Length](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2773396/208880) header to let the receiver know how much data to expect.

Comment: Doesn't work, I already have that header sent to the client.

Comment: @maximedupre I wonder is it because the mp3 file is too large?

Comment: What is considered "too large"?

Comment: if you need Range support then have a look at https://github.com/danvk/RangeHTTPServer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the video file I was using was corrupted (maybe it had some dropped frames or something like that). I tested with multiple other .mp4 and it worked like a charm.

All you really need to play a video file (or more accurately stream a video file as pointed by @hrunting) as far as http headers for the response are concerned is:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.5.0
Date: Sat, 02 Jan 2016 02:45:34 GMT
Content-type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 33455269
Last-Modified: Sat, 02 Jan 2016 02:45:27 GMT
```

I think even the `Server`, `Date` and `Last-Modified` headers aren't mandatory (they are sent automatically by [`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)).

As pointed by @qarma and @hrunting, if you want to enable the user to jump to a specific time in video, you should support the `Range` header. It's simply a good idea to support the `Range` header as it is sent by default by Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To stream videos you should support at least [range requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) and [transfer-encoding: chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

As far as I can see `http.server` does not support that directly. You can of course implement that on top.

Alternatively use a simple framework, e.g. `bottle` (one file, already supports both) or `cherrypy` (more solid, multi-threaded, etc)

You can also get by without any Python code, e.g. if you use `nginx`

Comment: But is it streaming that I am attempting to do? Am I not trying to simply serve a video file? Maybe it's the same thing.

Comment: Also why do the browsers download for only 5/7 seconds?

Comment: I don't see why I would need to support range requests, as I want to transfer the entire file and I also don't see why I would need to support transfer-encoding: chunked, as the server already provides a Content-Length.

Comment: @maximedupre capture network traffic against a reference server and go from there. Range makes sense if user may jump to a specific time in video. Broken pipe suggests that browsers wants less data than is sent, quite possible if you ignored range header.

Comment: http://ronallo.com/blog/html5-video-everything-i-needed-to-know/ and also "buffering" section of http://www.chromium.org/audio-video

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, @qarma is right. To stream videos, you need to use a library or framework that supports, at the very least, `Range:` headers.

But, you are not /trying/ to stream video. The browser is doing it for you. When you return the `video/mp4` content type, the browser, which knows how to stream video itself, immediately switches to a streaming mode. It stops the file download it had going (the source of your pipe errors), and restarts with a `Range:` header. It leverages existing media player code within the browser to do so. Since the `SimpleHTTPServer` class doesn't support the `Range:` header, it doesn't handle the response properly.

If you want to prevent this streaming behavior and force the browser to download the file without playing it, then return the `Content-Disposition` header forcing it to treat the video file as a downloaded file rather than as a piece of content to be rendered.

Here's some code based on your initial question that does what you want:

```
import http.server

class SuperHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        path = self.path
        encodedFilePath = 'file.mp4'

        with open(encodedFilePath, 'rb') as videoFile:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'video/mp4')
            self.send_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + encodedFilePath)
            self.end_headers()
            self.copyfile(videoFile, self.wfile)

server_address = ('', 8000)
handler_class = SuperHandler
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, handler_class)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Theoretically, you also send back `Accept-Ranges: none`, but Chrome, at least, seems to ignore that.

Comment: I still don't see why I would need to support the `Range` headers. I always want the full video file to be transferred, not just part of the video. Maybe you are saying that because as @qarma said, "the user may jump to a specific time in video", but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem (although thanks for the tip). When you say: "It stops the file download it had going (the source of your pipe errors), and restarts with a Range: header", you are right, but it only occurs in Chrome (not Firefox). And no, I don't want to download the video file, I want to play it in the browser.

Comment: I have actually found the solution to my problem, I will post it as an answer, but thank you for the help.