# How to keep Werkzeug from crashing after NGINX closes pipe?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I have a Werkzeug server running behind NGINX. When a client disconnects while waiting for the Werkzeug server to respond, NGINX closes the pipe to Werkzeug. When the python program writes the response to Werkzeug, the following exception occurs and Werkzeug crashes:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "server.py", line 81, in 
>       app.run(host=args.host, port=args.port, debug=False)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 843, in run
>       run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 694, in run_simple
>       inner()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 659, in inner
>       srv.serve_forever()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 499, in serve_forever
>       HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 238, in serve_forever
>       self._handle_request_noblock()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 297, in _handle_request_noblock
>       self.handle_error(request, client_address)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in **init**
>       self.finish()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
>       self.wfile.close()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
>       self.flush()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
>       self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
>   socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Is there some configuration option I'm missing to keep it from crashing? Normally all exceptions are caught and a 500 error returned, with the server remaining alive.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess from the debug trace and without reading the source code, you are probably closing the socket prematurely.

> Your server process has received a SIGPIPE writing to a socket. This usually happens when you write to a socket fully closed on the other (client) side. This might be happening when a client program doesn't wait till all the data from the server is received and simply closes a socket (using close function).
>
> In a C program you would normally try setting to ignore SIGPIPE signal or setting a dummy signal handler for it. In this case a simple error will be returned when writing to a closed socket. In your case a python seems to throw an exception that can be handled as a premature disconnect of the client.

[How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe)

Comment: Nginx closes the socket when the client disconnects. When python writes the response, the error occurs, and werkzeug doesn't catch it.