# Broken Pipe Error python while trying to netcat large file into termbin.com

Tags: python, linux, netcat

I am working a new command line tool https://github.com/a7i7/HoldMyFile .
But I am facing some problem with the following function:

```
def netcat(hostname, port, content):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hostname, port))
    s.sendall(content)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    response = ''
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data == "":
            break
        data = repr(data)
        response = response + data
    s.close()
    response = response[:-3][1:]
    return response
```

Whenever I call netcat('termbin.com',9999,content) and content has around 1 MB of data in it, the code exits with the following error message "socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" . 
Now if I send 1 MB of data from the linux shell using 
`cat data.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` all the data is successfully sent. 
I even tried running the same command from the linux shell using os.system from python. still the broken pipe error is encountered. Kindly help me fix this

Comment: In which line of code the exception raised?

Comment: @Samuel s.sendall(content)

but if I remove s.shutdown(socket.WR) then there is no exception, but all the data is not transferred either.

Comment: Did you checked this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe

Comment: 671872 bytes seem to be the limit. I read the link but still am not quite sure how to get this fixed. Is it likely that since python is slow termbin.com server might have closed the connection before all data has been transferred?

Comment: Yup. You can check this python netcat example though  https://gist.github.com/f35a7252babdf77c8421

Comment: Tried it. Doesnt work. Same problem. Incomplete data transferred