# client socket not able to get connected to server socket, [Errno 32] Broken pipe error

Tags: python, sockets

I have written a client-server python program where the client can send the data to the server. But when the client is trying to connect with the server I am getting the following error.

```
[Errno 110] Connection timed out
Sending Key to Server
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "client.py", line 43, in <module>
       s.send(str(id))
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I tried the following solutions
[Broken Pipe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014252/socket-error-errno-32-broken-pipe) and [How to prevent Broken pipe error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe) but none of them solved the issue.

**Here are my client and server code**

client.py

```
import socket
import os
import subprocess
from optparse import OptionParser
from random import randint 

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
    print "Socket has been successfully created"
except socket.error as err:
    print "socket creation failed with error %s" %(err)

# The Manager Address and port 

host_ip='192.168.43.123'
port =10106

# Generates a random number say xxxx then its client id becomes 'clxxxx' and home directory made at the server as '/home/clxxxx' with permissions 700
def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

id=random_with_N_digits(4)
id="cl"+ str(id)

# Looks for a public key in .ssh folder if temp.pub not present. If not found generates a ssh public private key and sends it to manager which then copies it to the server
subprocess.call(["bash","keygen.sh"])


#s = socket.socket()

try:
    s.connect((host_ip,port))
    print "the socket has successfully connected to Backup Server IP == %s" %(host_ip)

except socket.error as err:
    print err

f = open('temp.pub','r')
print "Sending Key to Server"

j = "-"
s.send(str(id))
l=f.read(8192)
while(l):
    print 'Sending...'
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(8192)

try:
    client_id=s.recv(1024)
    data=s.recv(12)
    ip=s.recv(24)
    print  client_id,
    print  data, ip
except:
    print "An Unknown Error Occurred!"

f.close()

# Writes the parameters of client in the file 'backup_dir.txt'
with open('backup_dir.txt','w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(client_id)
    the_file.write('\n')
    the_file.write(data)
    the_file.write('\n')
    the_file.write(ip)
    the_file.write('\n')
f.close()


s.close()
```

server.py

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
    print "Socket has been successfully created"
except socket.error as err:
    print "socket creation failed with error %s" %(err)

port = 10106

s.bind(('', port))
print("socket binded to %s port" %port)

s.listen(10)
print("socket is listening")

while(True):
    print("waiting for a connection")
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Got a connection from", addr,c)
    clientID =(c.recv(8192))
    key =(c.recv(8192))
    print clientID
    print key

    with open("temp.pub", 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(key)
    note=subprocess.check_output("./test_user.sh "+ clientID, shell=True)
    note = str(note)
    print(len(note))
    flag, path, serverIP = note.split(":")
    print(flag)
    print(path)
    print(serverIP)
    if flag:
        c.send(clientID)
        c.send(path)
        c.send(serverIP)
        os.remove("temp.pub")
    else:
        c.send("Unable to add Client.")
```

How do I fix this problem so that the client can send the data to the server without any error? 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: ideally you want to create the socket in the client the same way as the server.. meaning using `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` in the client.py code to make sure the correct protocol is used..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yeah one of my friend suggested me that and I tried it, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: ok then it's maybe a local or some firewall which is in the way?

Comment: The access point that I am using is a hotspot from my mobile without any proxy. Still, if that might be the case can you please elaborate how can I check if the issue is due to the firewall?

Comment: *"The access point that I am using is a hotspot from my mobile without any proxy"* well it can be a firewall at the mobile phone provider i assume you are tethering your mobile phone (edge/gprs/3g/4g) data?

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, I am not running a server on mobile phone connection I am just providing an access point through mobile phone connection. I have run various socket connections this way for my raspi, it works and I also tried to run it through connecting to the same wifi to both server and client but the error remains same.

Comment: No, I am not tethering my mobile phone I am providing [hotspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotspot_(Wi-Fi)) through it to both the client and server.

Comment: well iam out of options.. but it's pretty clear that or the server or client is cleary not in the same wifi network then..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Client and Server both are connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: then i would suggest using `ping ip` to see if that works, to check if the server and client machine can ping one and other.. To rule out network problems between them.

Comment: Yeah, both server and client are able to ping to each other and for confirmation, I also checked in Network that both are connected to the same wifi.

Comment: @RaymondNijland It was a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error resolved.
It was due to the firewall issue as @RaymondNijland was mentioning, Thanks.
I added the rule in the firewall to allow the following port for Socket Connection and it worked.

```
sudo ufw allow 10106
```