# Setting read timeout on socket

Tags: sockets, network-programming, rust

I have a TCP echo server in Rust that randomly drops messages. I am trying to set a read timeout on the client socket.

**client**

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::str;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader, Write};
use std::time::Duration;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

fn main() {
    let remote: SocketAddr = "127.0.0.1:8888".parse().unwrap();
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect_timeout(&remote, Duration::from_secs(1)).expect("Could not connect to server");
    stream.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_millis(1))).expect("Could not set a read timeout");
    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();
        let mut buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read from stdin");
        stream.write(input.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write to server");

        let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);

        reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buffer).expect("Could not read into buffer");
        print!("{}", str::from_utf8(&buffer).expect("Could not write buffer as string"));
    }
}
```

**server**

```
extern crate rand;

use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::thread;
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

use std::io::{Error, Read, Write};

fn flip() -> bool {
    let choices = [true, false];
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    *rng.choose(&choices).unwrap()
}

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let mut buf = [0; 512];
    loop {
        let bytes_read = stream.read(&mut buf)?;
        if bytes_read == 0 {
            return Ok(());
        }
        if flip() {
            return Ok(());
        }
        stream.write(&buf[..bytes_read])?;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8888").expect("Could not bind");
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Err(e) => eprintln!("failed: {}", e),
            Ok(stream) => {
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream).unwrap_or_else(|error| eprintln!("{:?}", error));
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `set_read_timeout` call does not seem to be doing anything; the client still waits for a few seconds between the server dropping the message and aborting the connection, even if I set the duration to 1ms.

```
$ rustc tcp-client-timeout.rs && ./tcp-client-timeout
test
test
foo
foo
bar


thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to write to server: Error { repr: Os { code: 32, message: "Broken pipe" } }', src/libcore/result.rs:906:4
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Comment: FYI, `flip` could just be `fn flip() -> bool { rand::thread_rng().gen() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `set_read_timeout` call does not seem to be doing anything; the client still waits for a few seconds between the server dropping the message and aborting the connection

This is not the experience I had running your code. In fact, when I add an `eprintln` directly after the `read_until` call, it prints almost immediately when the server decides to drop the connection. Indeed, the problem is not in the reading but the *writing*, as you can see from your error message:

> thread 'main' panicked at '**Failed to write to server**:

I'm guessing that you aren't "waiting a few seconds", but are instead pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times (the blank lines between "bar" and the panic message also indicate this). Your read timeout is working just fine — the problem is that [you are trying to write to a socket that the other side has already closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe):

```
if flip() {
    return Ok(());
}
```

By exiting the loop, you are closing the socket completely. You can either detect this on the client side or continue the server loop instead of exiting it.