# Modbus python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, ethernet

I want to try MODBUS with Python, I am using the below code with `sudo python3 modbus_master.py` code. But I have these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modbus_master.py", line 22, in <module>
    sock.send(req)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Why I see broken pip what is the reason for?

That is my basic code:

```
import socket
import struct
import time

TCP_IP='192.166.1.30'
TCP_PORT=502
BUFFER_SIZE=0
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()

sock.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
sock.listen(5)

unitId=16
functionCode=5
print("\n,Switching plug on")
coilId=1
req = struct.pack('12B', 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06,
                  int(unitId), int(functionCode), 0x00, int(coilId),
                  0xff, 0x00)
sock.send(req)
print("TX: (%s)" % req)

time.sleep(2)

print('\nCLOSING SOCKET')
sock.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe)