# Search for a file from server and send to client

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

I want to make a program that can search for file in the server's computer, if the file exist in the server notify the client if it doesn't notify the client then print the result to the client and then send the file to the client.

This is my client side code

## client.py

```
    import socket

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 2000

    def find_all(search):
        socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket1.connect((HOST, PORT))
        search = input("Enter file name: ")
        socket1.send(search.encode('utf-8'))
        found = socket1.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        result = socket1.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(result)
        not_found = socket1.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

        with open(result, 'wb') as file_to_write:
            while True:
                result = socket1.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                print(result)
                if not result:
                    break
                file_to_write.write(result.encode('utf-8'))
        file_to_write.close()
        print('Download Successful')
        socket1.close()
        return


    print(find_all('search'))
```

This is the error from the client side

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cient.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(find_all('search'))
  File "/client.py", line 16, in find_all
    with open(result, 'wb') as file_to_write:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

This is my server side code:

## server.py

```
    import socket
    import os
    from pathlib import Path

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 2000
    socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket1.bind((HOST, PORT))
    socket1.listen(5)

    conn, addr = socket1.accept()
    result = []
    search = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    path = str(Path.home())
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if search in files:
            found = socket1.send("File found".encode('utf-8'))
            print('data=%s', found)
            result.append(os.path.join(root, search))
            socket1.send(result.encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            not_found = socket1.send("File not found".encode('utf-8'))
            print('data=%s', not_found)
    while True:
        with open('result', "rb") as file_to_send:
            for result in file_to_send:
                conn.sendall(result.encode('utf-8'))
        print('Send Successful')
```

This the error from the server

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/server.py", line 22, in <module>
    not_found = socket1.send("File not found".encode('utf-8'))
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

When i ran the both codes it works but doesn;t present the output to the client if file doesn't exist or does exist in the folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe)