# Django error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, django, broken-pipe

sometimes on my site when I'm working on my local version, I get this error in my console :

```
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Does anyone have an idea to where it come from and how to prevent this because it's slowing down the site a lot.

Comment: Are you using the dev server ? If so, your question is probably already answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912672/django-broken-pipe-in-debug-mode

Comment: This usually means the browser discontinued the connection while the server was still trying to generate the page. It's safe to ignore these (they only happen on the dev server).

Answer (score 4):

I got this when the database connection was hanging between dev server and db (using Amazon RDS).

Answer (score 2):

This might be because you are using two method for inserting data into database and this cause the site to slow down.

```
def add_subscriber(request, email=None):
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email_field']
    e = Subscriber.objects.create(email=email).save()  <==== 
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

eg. in above function error is where arrow is pointing
the correct way to implement above is

```
def add_subscriber(request, email=None):
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email_field']
    e = Subscriber.objects.create(email=email)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```