# Exception occurring when loading django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I just upgraded to Django 1.5 and am seeing this exception when loading templates:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50545)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/home/redacted/.virtualenvs/redacted/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 150, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

This only happens the first time the template loads. All subsequent requests serve the template without issue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is just an [old quirk with the dev server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913160/2040872).  The [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444) is resolved as won't fixed.