# Django 3.2.3 - 3.2.6 broken pipe error on dev server

Tags: python, django

I tried beget and digital ocean, different Django-projects (my own and examples) and every time i try to send request to server from my PC am getting

```
[05/Oct/2021 12:26:24,844] - Broken pipe from ('94.72.62.225', 53959)
```

I do same things every time:

```
 python3 -m venv env
 . env/bin/activate
 pip install -r requirements.txt
 python3 manage.py makemigrations
 python3 manage.py migrate
 set ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] in settings.py ( ALLOWED_HOSTS=['server_id'] also checked )
 python3 manage.py rusnerver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

tools to send requests - google chrome, postman, curl

Comment: this is a issue with django's development server. It only happens in development server, it won't happen in production.

Comment: 0. it was fixed [here](https://github.com/django/django/commit/9253042d53d61b23b3f727a00c41e8089be73836)

Comment: 1. it works for me a month ago

Comment: If you want in detail, see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913160/14886355)

Comment: 2. it is useless info - it is most common answer that do not give any info

Comment: so you mean that the only one case to user django developemnt server is running on localhost?

Comment: You're running the dev server on a hosted server and are getting this error when you access it?

Comment: yes, i am running dev server with manage.py runserver on digital ocean droplet - hosted server - and get this error

Comment: The dev server is intended to be used locally. You should serve your app behind a webserver (nginx) if it's running on a server

Comment: Write this as answer - i cant decide that by existed questions on stack overflow, so mb it will help someone too

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think I answered your problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69451088/14886355)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. This issue only exists in devserver. The issue won't exist when you set `DEBUG=FALSE`. You are running a development server in production, don't do that. Here is a community tutorial which will guide you to set up Django with Postgres and Nginx: [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) in Production.

This issue was discussed and here's the ticket: [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444).

In that ticket's comments, there is a quite clear explanation:

> According to many sources the 'Broken Pipe' is a normal browser quirk. For example, the browser reads from the socket and then decides that the image it's been reading apparently didn't change. The browser now this (forcefully) closes the connection because it does not need more data. The other end of this socket (the python runserver) now raises a socket exception telling the program that the client 'Broke the socket pipe'.

Comment: simple answer - 
python3 manage.py runserver
 just to test on localhost

Comment: do I have to set `DEBUG = False` in settings.py file ?